# How can I view the sum of all dividends received in one given year on Mint?

Tags: dividends, mint.com

How can I view the sum of all dividends received in one given year on Mint?

This can't be done in the transactions tab according to https://help.mint.com/Accounts-and-Transactions/888963121/Why-can-t-I-filter-transactions-by-date.htm ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/save/https://help.mint.com/Accounts-and-Transactions/888963121/Why-can-t-I-filter-transactions-by-date.htm)):

> While transactions are automatically sorted by date, it is not currently possible to filter for a specific date range.

-> one can only view the sum of dividends and gains received since the creation of the Mint account.

I tried to create a report, following https://help.mint.com/888960571/How-do-I-get-reports-on-my-financial-activity.htm ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200927035939/https://help.mint.com/888960571/How-do-I-get-reports-on-my-financial-activity.htm)), but I couldn't find a way to place dividends on the graphs.

---

Screenshot of the Mint transactions tab with the `category = Dividend & Cap Gains` filter:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the help feature in Mint? They even have a live chat option now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer, with the new Mint UI (June 2022): go to https://mint.intuit.com/transactions and use filters:

[image]

---

Old answer, for the old Mint UI:

One can use the Google Chrome extension [A Bit Better Mint](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/a-bit-better-mint/nmcngapjgfglappdmacpaooicikdcpbb):

[image]

Or one can manually edit the URL as explained on https://scottpdawson.com/view-transactions-within-date-range-in-mint/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200927225112/https://scottpdawson.com/view-transactions-within-date-range-in-mint/)):

> Mint Transactions URL Structure: `https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:{QUERY_GOES_HERE}`
> The magical part is QUERY_GOES_HERE, and that's where we have the syntax for startDate and endDate. For example, for FY2019, use this:
> `"startDate":"01/01/2019","endDate":"12/31/2019"`

Turns out the query can contain more than just the date:

> If you want to group this with a query by category, transaction name,
> tag, or the contents of the notes field *(this one blew my mind, since
> I've wished for this for awhile)*, I've got you covered.
>
> - **category:** "query":"category=:Groceries"
> - **transaction name (description):** "query":"Wegmans"
> - **tag:** "query":"tag:strawberries"
> - **notes:** "query":"notes:lunch with Joe"
> - **grouping a few together:** "query":"description:Silver Queen Farms, tag:strawberries"

Examples:

- Dividends & Cap Gains in [2030](https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B%22startDate%22:%2201/01/2030%22,%22endDate%22:%2212/31/2030%22,%22query%22:%22category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains%22%7D), [2029](https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B%22startDate%22:%2201/01/2029%22,%22endDate%22:%2212/31/2029%22,%22query%22:%22category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains%22%7D), [2028](https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B%22startDate%22:%2201/01/2028%22,%22endDate%22:%2212/31/2028%22,%22query%22:%22category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains%22%7D), [2027](https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B%22startDate%22:%2201/01/2027%22,%22endDate%22:%2212/31/2027%22,%22query%22:%22category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains%22%7D), [2026](https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B%22startDate%22:%2201/01/2026%22,%22endDate%22:%2212/31/2026%22,%22query%22:%22category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains%22%7D), [2025](https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B%22startDate%22:%2201/01/2025%22,%22endDate%22:%2212/31/2025%22,%22query%22:%22category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains%22%7D), [2024](https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B%22startDate%22:%2201/01/2024%22,%22endDate%22:%2212/31/2024%22,%22query%22:%22category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains%22%7D), [2023](https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B%22startDate%22:%2201/01/2023%22,%22endDate%22:%2212/31/2023%22,%22query%22:%22category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains%22%7D), [2022](https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B%22startDate%22:%2201/01/2022%22,%22endDate%22:%2212/31/2022%22,%22query%22:%22category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains%22%7D)
- Dividends & Cap Gains in 2021: [https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B"startDate":"01/01/2021","endDate":"12/31/2021","query":"category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains"%7D](https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B%22startDate%22:%2201/01/2021%22,%22endDate%22:%2212/31/2021%22,%22query%22:%22category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains%22%7D)
- Dividends & Cap Gains in 2020: [https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B"startDate":"01/01/2020","endDate":"12/31/2020","query":"category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains"%7D](https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B%22startDate%22:%2201/01/2020%22,%22endDate%22:%2212/31/2020%22,%22query%22:%22category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains%22%7D)
- Dividends & Cap Gains in 2019: [https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B"startDate":"01/01/2019","endDate":"12/31/2019","query":"category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains"%7D](https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B%22startDate%22:%2201/01/2019%22,%22endDate%22:%2212/31/2019%22,%22query%22:%22category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains%22%7D)
- Dividends & Cap Gains in 2018: [https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B"startDate":"01/01/2018","endDate":"12/31/2018","query":"category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains"%7D](https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B%22startDate%22:%2201/01/2018%22,%22endDate%22:%2212/31/2018%22,%22query%22:%22category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains%22%7D)
- [Dividends & Cap Gains in between 2010 and 2030](https://mint.intuit.com/transaction.event#location:%7B%22startDate%22:%2201/01/2010%22,%22endDate%22:%2212/31/2030%22,%22query%22:%22category=:Dividend%20%26%20Cap%20Gains%22%7D)

Thanks to [basbryan](https://www.reddit.com/user/basbryan) for pointing out these solutions to me on https://redd.it/j0ki3u.